# My JAR file only executes on a double-click by opening a black window with one line but disappears before it is readable

Tags: java, executable-jar, jcreator

When I created the program using JCreator on computer A, I can execute the program by double-clicking on the jar file, however when I brought the exact folder holding the jar file to a different computer without JCreator but with Java installed, a black screen that looked like command prompt appeared with one line of text instead of the opening JFrame.  However, before I can read the line the command prompt looking screen disappears and ends the program.  Can someone explain what is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: You can run the Jar in a cmd window using `java -jar yourJar.jar` and check the output/error.

Answer (score 0):

The jar is throwing an Exception before it can show any windows or take any action. To see the Exception it's throwing, run the jar via the command prompt instead of double-clicking it.

More info here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/win32.html

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have a problem with the classpath of the jar looking for a resource that was being provided by JCreator but it can't find it, now that the directory has been moved. Use java -jar {jarfileName} to execute your jar file at the cmd prompt. You should then be able to see what is missing.

Hope this helps.